# Add SML syntax highlighting in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode

How can I configure Xcode so that I get syntax highlighting when using [Standard ML](http://www.smlnj.org/)? Is this even possible with Xcode?

Comment: You may need to create a plugin or language definition. There isn't much documentation, but some examples such as https://maniacdev.com/xcode-plugins are available.